# How to create a struct holding a pointer to another struct of unspecified type?

Tags: c, struct, casting, segmentation-fault, malloc

This is the struct that will contain another (variable) struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char * mem_addr;
    char * name;
    int option;
    void * struct_pointer;
} Handle;
```

I do not know what that struct will be as I want to have a selection of structs available to be nested, and later cast to a correct type as necessary. An example could be:

```
typedef struct{
    char *  policy;
    int     size;
    char *  addr;
} PS_call_struct;
```

I initialise those structs with this function:

```
threadHandle * createHandle(char * mem_addr, char * name, int option, void * struct_pointer){
    threadHandle * new = malloc(sizeof(threadHandle));

    new->mem_addr = malloc(strlen(mem_addr)+1);
    strcpy(new->mem_addr,mem_addr);

    new->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(new->name,name);

    new->option = malloc(sizeof(int));
    new->option = option;

    new->struct_pointer = malloc(strlen(struct_pointer)+1);
    strcpy(new->struct_pointer,struct_pointer);

    return new;
}
```

and this one:

```
PS_call_struct * createPS_call_struct(char *policy, int size, char *addr){
    PS_call_struct * new = malloc(sizeof(PS_call_struct));

    new->policy = malloc(strlen(policy)+1);
    strcpy(new->policy, policy);

    new->size = malloc(sizeof(int));
    new->size = size;

    new->addr = malloc(strlen(addr)+1);
    strcpy(new->addr, addr);        

    return new;
}
```

Once I want to use the nested struct I cast it. I test it as follows:

```
PS_call_struct * ps1 = createPS_call_struct(&h, 999, &k);
Handle * write_handle = createHandle(SRV_SOCK_PATH, "thread_cream",777,ps1);
PS_call_struct * techk = (PS_call_struct* )(write_handle->struct_pointer);
```

Now I have a problem as I can not access any of the values after recasting. I can access values of `ps1` without problems but values of `techk` are mostly null. I can not specify that struct type like below, as I would like to have the option of a utilising another type of struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char * mem_addr;
    char * name;
    int option;
    int write_byte_size;
    PS_call_struct * struct_pointer;
} Handle;
```

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is actually possible or whether just my approach to this is incorrect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strlen` function expect a pointer to a null terminated string.  In `createHandle`, `struct_pointer` is not a null terminated string but a pointer to `PS_call_struct`, so this won't work as you expect.

What you actually want is to simply assign the pointer to `struct_pointer`:

```
new->struct_pointer = struct_pointer;
```

Also, this doesn't make sense:

```
new->option = malloc(sizeof(int));
new->option = option;
```

Because the field `option` is not a pointer but simply an `int`, so get rid of the `malloc` call.